# Animate -> Slide to left not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div: "id1" and I want to slide to this "id2"

I have a button on `<div id="id1">`  that has:

```
<a href="#id2">next</a>
```

and I have this script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#next-button2').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 2000);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

That I took from [this Site](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/), but its not working, any ideas why?

Comment: JSFiddle? The HTML & CSS would be nice too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is looking to bind the animation function to a DOM object with id = `next-button2`

Change your HTML to:

```
<a id="next-button2" href="#id2">next</a>
```

so that your JQuery can bind the click function to the right DOM object.

Also, you'll need to make the actual animation bind to the correct object, so change:

```
$('html, body')
```

to:

```
$('#id1')
```

If you want a more in depth answer you may want to provide more HTML, JS / JQ, and CSS to look at.

Comment: ok, thanks very much for the reply, i changed it: <a id="next-button2", but its still not working :( Perhaps something wrong with the script? :X

Comment: @gn66 I made an edit; the actual animation was not pulling the correct DOM object either.  See the second portion of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/hA9Sp/1/

I think you are just missing the id "next-button2" in your link. I haven't edited any of the javascript.

My test HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;height:100px;width:2000px;background-color:yellow;">
    <div id="id1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;">
        <a id="next-button2" href="#id2">next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="id2" style="position:absolute;right:0px;">
        id2
    </div>
</div>
```

If after that it still doesn't work, make sure that your javascript does actually run. Add an `alert("test");` or `console.log("test);` and see if anything happens.

Comment: very thanks for the reply! I must say it works, i'm gonna mark user3507600 as the correct answer just because he was first, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @gn66 Don't worry, as long as we were able to help ;)